# Git repo from Eclipse on W7 imported to Eclipse on Mac, why "compiler compliance level" error?

Tags: android, eclipse, git

I have a small Android app developed in Eclipse on Windows and versioned on Github. Now that I cloned and imported it from Github to Eclipse on a Macbook, I get the error that "Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.4' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties."

I looked around here, and this seems to have something to do with the java version, but the java sdk installed on the Macbook is SE 6, same as on the Windows machine. Also the Android sdk versions are the same (the latest). So I have no clue what's going on... Any ideas, suggestions, anyone?

Also,,, if I do these fixes, whatever they are, will I have a problem after pulling to the Windows machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you have JDK 6, you need to explicitly set compliance level Window--Preferences--Java-JRE--compilance level, change to 1.6.

It is eclipse level setting, so high possibility that it may happen on windows machine too.

Comment: Thanks for this. Strange thing... today I open the project that I closed yesterday after asking this question, without doing any changes to anything, and now the compliance level is set to 1.6. Either this happened automagically, or the error was/is a bug somewhere... Anyway, many thanks for the help.